Can't install thrift 0.10.0.0 in my local machine (OS -> 15.0.1)
running a rails migration 
bin/rails generate migration CreatePurgeRequest
is giving error
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/bundler-2.2.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in block in materialize': Could not find thrift-0.10.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`
But when i try t install  the missing gem it is giving the below error
ERROR:  Error installing thrift:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/thrift-0.10.0.0/ext
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby -I /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20241017-55212-j4qf7y.rb extconf.rb
checking for strlcpy() in string.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/thrift-0.10.0.0/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/thrift-0.10.0.0/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling binary_protocol_accelerated.c
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:404:68: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  404 |   VALUE thrift_binary_protocol_class = rb_const_get(thrift_module, rb_intern("BinaryProtocol"));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                       ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:404:68: note: '{' token is here
  404 |   VALUE thrift_binary_protocol_class = rb_const_get(thrift_module, rb_intern("BinaryProtocol"));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1811:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
 1811 |     {                                                   \
      |     ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:404:68: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  404 |   VALUE thrift_binary_protocol_class = rb_const_get(thrift_module, rb_intern("BinaryProtocol"));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1816:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
 1816 |     }
      |     ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:404:68: note: ')' token is here
  404 |   VALUE thrift_binary_protocol_class = rb_const_get(thrift_module, rb_intern("BinaryProtocol"));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:56: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                                                        ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:406:68: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  406 |   VERSION_1 = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("VERSION_1")));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                       ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:406:68: note: '{' token is here
  406 |   VERSION_1 = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("VERSION_1")));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1811:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
 1811 |     {                                                   \
      |     ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:406:68: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  406 |   VERSION_1 = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("VERSION_1")));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1816:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
 1816 |     }
      |     ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:406:68: note: ')' token is here
  406 |   VERSION_1 = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("VERSION_1")));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:56: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                                                        ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:407:71: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  407 |   VERSION_MASK = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("VERSION_MASK")));
      |                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                       ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:407:71: note: '{' token is here
  407 |   VERSION_MASK = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("VERSION_MASK")));
      |                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1811:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
 1811 |     {                                                   \
      |     ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:407:71: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  407 |   VERSION_MASK = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("VERSION_MASK")));
      |                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1816:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
 1816 |     }
      |     ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:407:71: note: ')' token is here
  407 |   VERSION_MASK = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("VERSION_MASK")));
      |                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:56: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                                                        ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:408:68: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  408 |   TYPE_MASK = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("TYPE_MASK")));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                       ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:408:68: note: '{' token is here
  408 |   TYPE_MASK = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("TYPE_MASK")));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1811:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
 1811 |     {                                                   \
      |     ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:408:68: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  408 |   TYPE_MASK = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("TYPE_MASK")));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1816:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
 1816 |     }
      |     ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:408:68: note: ')' token is here
  408 |   TYPE_MASK = rb_num2ll(rb_const_get(thrift_binary_protocol_class, rb_intern("TYPE_MASK")));
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:56: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                                                        ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:459:18: error: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  459 |   rbuf_ivar_id = rb_intern("@rbuf");
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                       ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:459:18: note: '{' token is here
  459 |   rbuf_ivar_id = rb_intern("@rbuf");
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1811:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
 1811 |     {                                                   \
      |     ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:459:18: error: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Werror,-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
  459 |   rbuf_ivar_id = rb_intern("@rbuf");
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1816:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
 1816 |     }
      |     ^
binary_protocol_accelerated.c:459:18: note: ')' token is here
  459 |   rbuf_ivar_id = rb_intern("@rbuf");
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sidmallik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:1826:56: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
 1826 |         __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
      |                                                        ^
10 errors generated.
make: *** [binary_protocol_accelerated.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/gems/thrift-0.10.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/sidmallik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@emailmarketing/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/thrift-0.10.0.0/gem_make.out

i have tried similar commands like
gem install thrift -v '0.8.0' -- --with-cppflags='-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0'
and
bundle config build.thrift "--with-cppflags=\"-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wno-shift-negative-value\""
but same still issue is not resolved
Any suggestion will be helpful

Trying to install an ancient version of Ruby on the latest version of OSX is not trivial.  Updating to Ruby 3 will likely provide an easier path.
